# C# - Trouble in printing array in descending order

Tags: c#, sorting

I am accepting a number from the user, called `originally_entered_number_inString`, which is `n` digits long. Now, if that number is positive, it prints that number in ascending order. If negative, in descending. I got the positive part going for me, but the negative part is where I am getting stuck - it displays the negative number in descending order, but with a *-1* next to it.

Example: User enters `654568`. So there are 6 digits in that number and positive, so ascending - Result: `455668`. But if I enter `-584669`, it outputs `986654-1` If you see, the result is valid, just that it's taking a value of the hyphen (- (minus)) as `-1`, or something. Can you help me, please?

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace nkhl
{
    public class Program1
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");

            string originally_entered_number_inString = Console.ReadLine();
            int entered_number_inInt = Convert.ToInt32(originally_entered_number_inString);
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe number you entered is {0}.", entered_number_inInt);

            //Counting the number of digits in the entered number:
            int n = originally_entered_number_inString.ToString().Count();

            //entered_number_inInt is added to the array called array_of_the_numbers
            int[] array_of_the_numbers = entered_number_inInt.ToString().Select(o=> (int)char.GetNumericValue(o)).ToArray();

            if(originally_entered_number_inString.Contains("-"))
            {

              Console.WriteLine("\nThis is a negative number, so it will print the given number in Descending order.");
              Array.Sort(array_of_the_numbers);
              Array.Reverse(array_of_the_numbers);

              Console.WriteLine("\nThe entered number has {0} digits.", n-1); //n-1 becuase it takes the minus (-) also as a character so it reads 4.
              Console.WriteLine("\n{0}, in descending order is", entered_number_inInt );

              foreach(var i in array_of_the_numbers)
              {
                Console.Write(i);
              }
            }

            else
            {
              Console.WriteLine("\nThe entered number has {0} digits.", n);
              Console.WriteLine("{0}, in ascending order is", entered_number_inInt);
              Array.Sort(array_of_the_numbers);
              foreach(var i in array_of_the_numbers) Console.Write(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, it is counting the minus as a digit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, this works for you?

```
string value = Console.ReadLine();
var negative = value.StartsWith("-");

var newValue = value.Replace("-", string.Empty);
var numbers = newValue
    .Select(c => (int)char.GetNumericValue(c))
    .ToArray();

Array.Sort(numbers);

if (negative) Array.Reverse(numbers);

foreach (var item in numbers){ 
    Console.Write(item);
}
```

Comment: OR, you could turn the string into a number, see if its less than zero, and take its absolute value

Comment: @Amy _i_ is `int`. What I need to do is, convert the final output to string and TrimEnd the last part.

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see this! I drafted and submitted later with my phone :)

Answer (score 1):

A negative number isn't just a number that "contains the minus sign" (12.0E-1 is a positive number), but it's a number that's smaller than 0. I suggest you come up with a more straightforward logic for your algorithm.

One one could be this: you first copy your input string in an integer variable

```
int intNumber = int.Parse(inputNumber);
```

check if the input number is negative

```
bool isNegative = (intNumber < 0);
```

then take its **absolute value** (that is just the number without sign)

```
int absNumber = Math.Abs(intNumber);
```

and put the digits into an array of integers

```
int[] intArray = absNumber.ToString().Select(digit=>int.Parse(digit.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Now you can sort really easy:

```
int[] sortedArray = Array.Sort(intArray);
if (isNegative)
    sortedArray = Array.Reverse(sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply `entered_number_inInt` if it is smaller then 0 so you don't parse `'-'` back into `-1`

```
(int)char.GetNumericValue('-') == -1
```

Other solution is to replace `'-'` in the string with `''`.

Comment: '-' is for the negative sign. That's why it's there. And where does `(int)char.GetNumericValue('-') == -1` go? It's throwing an error that reads <pre>main.cs(24,15): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

exit status 1</pre> I put it right after the first if statement (`if(originally_entered_number_inString.Contains("-"))`)